# ANSI encoded file converting to UTF-8 encoded file with php script?

Tags: php, linux, utf-8, character-encoding, converters

How can ANSI encoded file converting to UTF-8 encoded file with php, or any script, or any command line under linux?

Comment: ANSI isn't a type of character encoding...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, ANSI is not a type of character encoding. With ANSI, you need to find out what the encoding options are for the particular file that you're trying to read. First you should find out first if the file is already UTF-8 encoded, and if not, then simply encode it. Below, we check the encoding and if successful we return the file.

```
$output = false;
if( !mb_check_encoding( $myFile, 'UTF-8', true ) ):
   $output = mb_convert_encoding( $myFile, 'UTF-8' ); 
endif;
```

Then simply check if the encoding worked.

```
return $output ? $output : 'Failed encoding file!';
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! When I manually download that .csv file and open it with writing pad under windows, I seen is coded by ansi. Also I saving as in same file, just turning the file coding into utf-8. So I want to do the same with php, or with command line...

Comment: @MarcellNemeth If you can use the command line then I would probably use `iconv` for this. `iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 <infile >outfile` and of course adjust the variables accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I thinking too on that iconv command line... So is looks like this:

Comment: iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 </folder1/folder2/file_ansi.csv >/folder1/folder2/file_utf8.csv ?

Comment: @MarcellNemeth Yep that's exactly right. There are some caveats to using `iconv` in that it doesn't handle error reporting very well, so you may want to watch out for that.

Comment: Your command line is really working, but I have one problem: That command is working very well with ssh and really convert ANSI to utf-8. But when I try to start it by crontab, is make one empty file. Do you know why, or how I can fix it?

Comment: @MarcellNemeth You're saying that when you call your `.sh` file using a `cron job` it creates an `empty file`, yes? Please change your script so that it simply writes, `"Hello World"` to ensure file writing and cron execution. If that still doesn't work, then you have bigger issues. If it does work, then make a new question regarding using `iconv` in `cron tasks`. :)

Comment: Maybe I not fully understand you, or I give a wrong question... :) The problem is: If I start that command (iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 </folder1/file_ansi.txt >/folder1/file_utf8.txt) with ssh (winscp), is really convert the ansi encoded file to utf-8. So is fully working with ssh, with winscp. But when I add the same command line into crontab file, is make an empty file. That what I not understand, why not working with crontab?

Comment: Hey! I fix it! :) All that command I put into the .sh file and now working perfect with crontab as well!

Answer (score 1):

Not my answer but highlighting one of the comments on Ohgodwhy's answer:

If you can use the command line then I would probably use iconv for this.

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 <infile >outfile
```

and of course adjust the variables accordingly. –  Ohgodwhy